# Is it possible to mention people in a status update via the LinkedIn API?

Tags: linkedin-api

On the LinkedIn platform, mentioning other people on a status update is done by writing '@' followed by the name of the person. At this point, LinkedIn will show a list matching the name and the user can pick a person/company from it.

Is there a way to mention people while using the LinkedIn API?

For example, with the Twitter API, it is just necessary to type the @name and the system will do the job, this doesn't seem to work for LinkedIn.

Answer (score 4):

@-mentions are not presently supported in updates posted via LinkedIn's API.

Comment: Do you know if they are planned?

Answer (score -1):

According to the [latest docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/little-text-format?view=li-lms-2023-11), published November 2023, it now supports @-tagging.